# How can I push this headless piston?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Version: 1.9.4 - 1.12 (vanilla and/or spigot/bukkit/paper server)

How can I push the headless piston in the below picture against the wall?

Prohibited blocks/items:

> Hopper, all special minecart, elytra, activator/detector rail, written books, Armor stand, end rod, daylight sensor, depth strider, frost walker, Shield, No animals (only creeper egg and Skeleton/pig spawner), dispenser, dragon egg, slime block, chorus plant/flower, end crystal

[image: The headless piston + obsidian wall]

Comment: It is impossible to make a flying machine to push this without observers or slime blocks (pretty sure)

Comment: I want a flying machine, slimeless and observers_less.

Comment: Thats pretty impossible unfortunately :(

Comment: Can you give me your Discord ? i want to show you something in my server.

Answer (score 0):

Try placing a piston horizontally, then 2 observers placed horizontally in front of it (One block gap between piston and first observer). Next place another piston horizontally on the observer. Then leave a 1 block space, then place 3 more observers horizontally. Activate the first piston you placed orginally, and it should push the headless piston without activating it!

Video:

- 

Alternative:

- 